# XDocument.Load not available in expression shape (orchestration) in BizTalk 2010

Tags: linq-to-xml, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I need to load `XDocument` from within an expression shape in BizTalk 2010 orchestration. I can do it in `C#`, without any issues.

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Temp\Files\SampleFile.xml");
```

But in expression shape I don't have the `XDocument.Load method`. I would like to use `Linq to XML`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly and use the fully qualified type name in the expression shape:

```
System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(strUri);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: But watch out for serializability in orchestrations!